# Creating a reset() function using booleans in C++

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a class named Rectangle which has an initialization flag bool_init flag and many functions. It is easy to reset the information by creating a reset() function that returns bool_init flag = false. It can also be done with a pointer.

I then initialize the object with some random information, reset it and initialize it again and it works perfectly.

```
class Rectangle{
protected:
    double sidea, sideb;
    double peri;
    bool init_flag;

public:
    Rectangle()
    { init_flag = false; }

...

void get_perimeter()
{
    if(isInitialized())
        perimeter=2*(sidea + sideb);
}
void reset() {
    if (isInitialized())
        { init_flag = false; }
```

I also have a triangle class, that uses Rectangle to hold information about side a and about side b. My question is how do I create a reset() function for my triangle? I can not access the init_flag of rectangle as that is protected.

```
class Triangle{
protected:
    Rectangle sidea_sideb;
    double sidec;
    double perimeter;

public:
    bool isInitialized(){
        return sidea_sideb.isInitialized();
        }

...

void get_perimeter()
{
    if(sidea_sideb.isInitialized())
        perimeter=( (sidea_sideb.get_perimeter())/2 ) + sidec;
}
void reset() {
    if (isInitialized())
        { sidea_sideb.isInitialized() = false; }
```

I can work around this function and use a pointer in the sense of *this = triangle(), but I want to understand how to cast the isInitialized to become false. I have tried setting it to 0, but it returns lvalue required as left operand of assignment, so something on the left of the assignment operator must be wrong.

Comment: Design issues aside, wouldn't it make more sense to call `sidea_sideb.reset()`?

Comment: You need a function like `setUninitialized` to go with `isInitialized`. You should have `public` functions that do everything code outside the object might need to do to the object.

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss this. Yes that is exactly what I wanted to do, I guess I got lost as there are loads of lines of code in the files I am working with. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, you delegate all the other calls to `sidea_sideb` but somehow shy to do it with `reset`.

Comment: It just did not cross my mind. I don't know why.

Comment: The "think outside the box" solution is to always ensure that everything is initialized. If there is no sensible default value, remove the default constructor.